# ImportError: cannot import name 'cv2' from 'cv2'

Tags: opencv, anaconda

I'm using anaconda and installed OpenCV using conda-forge.

`conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

In my notebook I run this line of code

`from cv2 import cv2`

Unfortunately, get this error message:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'cv2' from 'cv2'  (C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\...\lib\site-packages\cv2.cp38-win_amd64.pyd)`

The weird thing is importing cv2 and running its functions works just fine.

```
# Works just fine
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('snek.jpg')
```

Here are some informations about my system if that helps?

```
conda version : 4.9.2
conda-build version : 3.20.5
python version : 3.8.5.final.0
platform : win-64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the opencv module you import this by running `import cv2`. The code you want to run tries to import a function/module called `cv2` from the `cv2` package, which does not exist.

Comment: Oh, apologies. I assumed that would work since that's the code that I was asked to work on. I guess if I wanted the code to work as is I could just run `from cv2 import *` but I'll just use `import cv2` and refactor the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using `from cv2 import *` will import all underlying functions and modules, e.g. `cv2.imread` could then be used by calling just `imread`. If you import the top level `cv2` package all functions will have to be called by using `cv2.function_name`. Hope that clears things up.